# dplyr+purrr: n() refers to map() groups, not local groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a parent dataset nesting multiple datasets (i.e. a tibble where each cell is a tibble) , where I want for each dataset, to find the number of rows of each group. Standard way, using a single dataset, would simply be to do `group_by(var) %>% mutate(nrow=n())`.

But now that I do this for multiple datasets with a `map()` call, it looks like the `n()` call refers to the (implicit) grouping made by `map()`, not the explicit grouping within my local dataset made by `group_by`?

Standard way for one single dataset, `n()` returns 50:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(., Species) %>%
  mutate(nrow=n())
```

Dataset of datasets:

```
 df <- data_frame(name=c("a", "b"), Data=list(iris, iris))
 df2 <- df %>%
          mutate(Data2=map(Data, ~group_by(., Species) %>%
                 mutate(nrow=n()) %>%
                 ungroup()))
```

but now `n()` returned 2?

```
df2[1,]$Data2[[1]]
```

Comment: dataset of datasets? what is that?

Comment: What do you want as a result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define the function outside of `mutate` it works fine (I assume this output is what you have in mind...)

```
fun <- function(x) {
  df <- group_by(x, Species) %>% 
    summarise(nrow = n())
}
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Data2=map(Data, fun))

df2$Data2
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Species  nrow
# <fctr> <int>
# 1     setosa    50
# 2 versicolor    50
# 3  virginica    50
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# Species  nrow
# <fctr> <int>
# 1     setosa    50
# 2 versicolor    50
# 3  virginica    50
```

Comment: well spotted! Indeed, it is referenced in bugs https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2080 and https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2623. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option, available since version `0.7.0` is to use `add_count()`, which will not conflict with the `map()`, and anyway simplifies the code:

```
# standard case:
iris %>%
  add_count(Species)

## df of df:
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Data2=map(Data, ~add_count(., Species)))
```